# make: invoke command for multiple targets of multiple files?

Tags: makefile

I looking to optimize an existing Makefile. It's used to create multiple plots (using Octave) for every logfile in a given directory using an scriptfile for every plot which takes a logfilename as an argument. In the Moment, I use one single rule for every kind of plot available, with a handwritten call to Octave, giving the specific scriptfile/logfile as an argument.

It would be nice, if every plot has "his" octave-script as a dependency (plus the logfile, of course), so only one plot is regenerated if his script is changed.

Since I don't want to type that much, I wonder how I can simplifiy this by using only one general rule to build "a" plot?

To make it clearer:

- Logfile: "$(LOGNAME).log"
- Scriptfile: "plot$(PLOTNAME).m" creates "$(LOGNAME)_$(PLOTNAME).png"

The first thing I had in mind:

```
%1_%2.png: %1.log
    $(OCTAVE) --eval "plot$<2('$<1')"
```

But this seems not to be allowed. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Find also similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745177/multi-wildcard-pattern-rules-of-gnu-make).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty crazy that make doesn't support this directly, I need it all the time.

The technique I use at the moment (with GNU make) (building on Didier Trosset's example):

```
define OCT_template

all: %_$(1).png

%_$(1).png: %.log
    $$(OCTAVE) --eval "plot$(1)('$$*')"

endef

PLOT_NAMES = plot1 plot2 plot3

$(foreach p, $(PLOT_NAMES), \
  $(eval $(call OCT_template,$(p))) \
)
```

This is [in the GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Eval-Function.html).

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! Very helpfull. Works like a charm -- just for the sake of making the Makefile smaller but more complicated ;)

Comment: This was super helpful.  One thing to note: the lack of `=' after define OCT_template is **critical**.  The make manual seems to indicate an = is required but its presence prevented call from expanding to anything.  Thanks.

Comment: @ Christopher Mason: The make manual you find most easily online is for 3.82, while most people's make is still 3.81. I believe this is one of the discrepancies.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern rules can use only 1 pattern (i.e. you cannot have `%1` and `%2`, just `%`).

Therefore, depending on the number of `PLOTNAME` and `LOGNAME` you have, choose the smallest and write as many pattern rules as needed.

```
%_plot1.png: %.log
        $(OCTAVE) --eval "plot1('$*')"
```

If you do not want to write as many rules as you have different plots (or logs), you can use a double Makefile mechanism. In the sub-Makefile, use the above command, but use a parameter for the plot name. In a master Makefile, call it with the various values of the plotname you want.

Makefile.sub:

```
%_$(PLOTNAME).png: %.log
        $(OCTAVE) --eval "plot$(PLOTNAME)('$*')"
```

Makefile:

```
all:
        $(MAKE) PLOTNAME=plot1 -f Makefile.sub
        $(MAKE) PLOTNAME=plot2 -f Makefile.sub
        $(MAKE) PLOTNAME=plot3 -f Makefile.sub
```

It saves writing the rule many times (and saves updating it as many times when needed), but then requires special handling for other targets than `all`, such as `clean`.

Comment: Hm, seems relatively complex, not like somehing I looked for. But I tried and it works, so thanks, anyways!

Comment: This is far clearest way how to achieve recursive dependency search using pattern rules. I would just use patterns for specification plot target:
`all : plot1 plot2 plot3` and then `plot% : \n\t$(MAKE) PLOTNAME=plot$* -f Makefile.sub`