# multi-wildcard pattern rules of GNU Make

Tags: makefile, design-patterns, gnu-make

I want to write something like regex:

```
SRC:="a.dat.1 a.dat.2"    
$(SRC): %.dat.%: (\\1).rlt.(\\2)    
      dat2rlt $^ $@
```

so that **a.dat.1** and **a.dat.2** will give **a.rlt.1** and **a.rlt.2**.

In GNU Make info page, it says "the % can be used only once".

Is there some trick to achieve this in GNU Make?

Comment: No, this is missing. A workaround is to add rules dynamically (with eval or include). See e.g. [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880975/make-invoke-command-for-multiple-targets-of-multiple-files) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545700/make-like-tool-that-supports-automatic-deletion-of-temp-files-and-regular-express).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are trying to do is not possible the way you suggest to do it, since - as you already mention - (GNU) make only allows a single stem '%', see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules:

> A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target
>   contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them).

Without it, creating such 'multi-dimensional' targets is cumbersome.

One way around this is by rebuilding the name of the dependency in the command (rather than in the dependency list):

```
SRC := a.dat.1 a.dat.2

all : $(SRC:%=%.dat2rlt)

%.dat2rlt :
    dat2rtl $(word 1,$(subst ., ,$*)).rlt.$(word 2,$(subst ., ,$*)) $*
```

Of course, however, this way you would lose the dependency, it will not rebuild once the rlt has been updated.

The only way I can see to address that is by generating the rules explicitly:

```
SRC := a.dat.1 a.dat.2

all : $(SRC)

define GEN_RULE
$1.dat.$2 : $1.rlt.$2
    dat2rtl $$< $$@
endef

$(foreach src,$(SRC),$(eval $(call GEN_RULE,$(word 1,$(subst ., ,$(src))),$(word 3,$(subst ., ,$(src))))))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using named variables, we can write more readable code (based on answer of Paljas):

```
letters:=a b c
numbers:=1 2 3 4

define GEN_RULE
$(letter).dat.$(number) : $(letter).rlt.$(number)
    ./rlt2dat $$< $$@
endef

$(foreach number,$(numbers), \
  $(foreach letter,$(letters), \
    $(eval $(GEN_RULE)) \
  ) \
)
```

We can generate `SRC` in a similar way. Note that using that method `SRC` will contain all the combinations. That may or may not be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of Erzsébet Frigó, you might additionally choose to:

- in the inner loop, `eval` not the macro itself but the result of `call`ing it
- name the macro after program you're calling, `dat2rtl`
- in combination, allowing you to

  - refer to the program name using make's `${0}`
  - define a target, `${0}s` (expanding to `dat2rts` - note the pluralization) with preconditions of all combinations of letters and numbers on which dat2r2 was called

Like this:

```
letters:=a b c
numbers:=1 2 3 4

define rlt2dat
${0}s::$(letter).dat.$(number)
$(letter).dat.$(number): $(letter).rlt.$(number)
    ./${0} $$< $$@
endef

$(foreach number,$(numbers), \
  $(foreach letter,$(letters), \
     $(eval $(call rlt2dat))))
```

allowing you to build all rlt2dat targets as:

`make rlt2dats`

Answer (score -2):

For the limited example you gave, you *can* use a pattern with one `%`.

```
SRC := a.dat.1 a.dat.2
${SRC}: a.dat.%: a.rlt.%    
      dat2rlt $^ $@
```

1. `$*` in the recipe will expand to whatever the `%` matched.
2. Note that the `"`s around your original macro are definitely wrong.
3. Have a look at `.SECONDEXPANSION` in the manual for more complicated stuff (or [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545700/make-like-tool-that-supports-automatic-deletion-of-temp-files-and-regular-express/3678807#3678807)).

Comment: sorry, maybe the example is not comprehensive, but I want to cover b.dat.1, b.dat.2, too.