# Makefile: multiple % in pattern rule

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

For example, I have the following project structure:

```
inc
|__ Header.h

src  
|__ App_main.c 

src-gen  
|__ App_1_1_header.c  
|__ App_1_2_header.c  
|__ App_2_1_header.c  
|__ App_2_2_header.c  
|__ App_2_3_header.c
```

and this makefile:

```
######## define include files #########  
INCLUDES := $(wildcard inc/*.h)
######## define paths to source and include files  #########  
vpath %.c src  
vpath %.c src-gen  
vpath %.h inc
######## define src folders ##########
SRC_DIR := src  
SRC_GEN_DIR := src-gen  
######## define source files #########
MAIN_SRC := src/App_main.c
APP_SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_GEN_DIR) -name "App_*.c")  
######## define object files #########
MAIN_OBJ := App_main.o 
APP_OBJ := $(pathsubst %.c,%.o, $(APP_SRC))  

%.o : %.c $(INCLUDES)  
    @echo '# Compiling: $@.c'  
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    @echo ' '  
app_%_%: $(MAIN_OBJ) App_%_%_Appheader.o 
    @echo '# Building target: $@'
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION)
```

In the case of the above project structure I need the following targets:

```
app_1_1 : App_main.o App_1_1_Header.o  
app_1_2 : App_main.o App_1_2_Header.o  
app_2_1 : App_main.o App_2_1.Header.o  
and so on..
```

As `Paljas` in his answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745177/multi-wildcard-pattern-rules-of-gnu-make) posted:

> A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target
> contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them)

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Best regards,
Usam

Comment: I don't see why you need two `%`.  Why don't you just have `app_% : $(MAIN_OBJ) App_%_Appheader.o`?  The `%` can just as easily match `1_1` etc. as it can match `1`.

Comment: You can construct explicit rules for every target by instantiating a parametrized canned recipe (see GNU make docs). For analyzing and dissecting strings you can use a command line tool combination or you may take a lookt at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which has a number of helper functions (esp. `glob-match`) for this purpose. The question however is if your naming scheme is so clear and self-explanatory that it is sufficient to structure your build. Most people intuitively think more in terms of separated storage locations (subdirectories) than name families.